# Mark changed entities as clean in Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I created a simple library for Doctrine2 for managing tree structures. In repository class I created method to preload childs of tree node. My method at first download all childs of specifed node until some depth as flat array and next recreates tree structure. It works ok but I want to set preloaded childs into node insted of default not initialized `PersistentCollection`. When I replace `PersistentCollection` by my `ArrayCollection` with fully loaded nodes Doctrine ”thinks” that i changed relations and tries set them again after persisting.

Is there any way to mark my node again as clean to prevent Doctrine from saving relations again?

Currenty my code looks like this:

```
public function prepopulateTree($parent, $depth = 0)
{
    $em = $this->_em;
    $metadata = $this->getClassMetadata();

    // Retrive flat array of child nodes using closure table.
    $childs = $this->getChildHierarchyQueryBuilder($parent, false, $depth)->getQuery()->getResult();

    $recursive = function($node, $parent, $currentDepth) use (&$em, &$metadata, &$childs, &$depth, &$recursive) {
        $collection = new ArrayCollection();

        foreach ($childs as $n => $child) {
            if ($child->getParentNode()->getId() === $node->getId()) {
                $collection->add($child);
                unset($childs[$n]);
            }
        }

        $node->setParentNode($parent);
        $node->setChildNodes($collection);

        if ($depth > 0 && $currentDepth >= $depth) {
            return;
        }

        foreach ($collection as $child) {
            $recursive($child, $node, $currentDepth + 1);
        }
    };

    $recursive($parent, null, 1);

    return $parent;
}
```

parentNode and childNodes are declared like in this example in Doctrine documentation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing

Comment: Can you give some example code?

Comment: I had an idea. childNodes are not owning side so i can clear this collection ($node->getChildNodes()->clear()), set childs (one by one using add method from PersistentCollection) and use method setDirty from PersistentCollection ($node->getChildNodes()->setDirty(false)). This works but i don't know if it is fine solution. I'm woried about compability with further versions of Doctrine.

Comment: That might actually work and I wouldn't worry about future compatibility with it.